# Typescript: Exclude properties provided in a Partial

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've written a function called `withDefaults` that takes a React component (a function really) and provides an object with default parameter values. It returns a function that that invokes the original React component (function) and merges the default parameters with the final set of parameters.

How can I make required parameters no longer required when they're provided in the default set?

```
function withDefaultProps<C extends React.ElementType>(Component: c) {
  const ResultComponent = Component as React.FunctionComponent;
  return (
    (defaultProps: Partial<React.ComponentProps<C>>) => (
      (finalProps: React.ComponentProps<C>) => (
        <ResultComponent {...defaultProps} {...finalProps}>
          {finalProps.children}
        </ResultComponent>
      )
    )
  )
}
```

So for example I have a component that requires `a` and `b` as properties.

```
type MyCompProps = {
  a: string,
  b: string
};

function MyComp(props: MyCompProps) {
  return null; // My react structure here
}

const MyPrefilledComp = withDefaultProps(MyComp)({ a: 'alwaysThisString' });
```

Here's where the Typescript error shows up. When I try to use `MyPrefilledComp` it still requires that I provide an `a` property even though its got a default value. How can I adjust my `withDefaulProps` method to make it optional, without making ALL the properties optional. I've tried Diff and Omit with keyOf but my Typescript is very beginner level so I may be doing those wrong.

```
// Typescript error: Property a is required
function MyApp() {
  return (
    <MyPrefilledComp b="a non default value" />
  )
}
```

I've attempted to simplify it and can easily see where the issue is, I'm just not sure how to fix it. Something like: `Omit<OriginalProps, Partial<OriginalProps>>` but with that partial being given a dynamic type based on the invocation.

```
function withDefaults(defaultProps: Partial<OriginalProps>) {
  return function wrapper(finalProps: OriginalProps) {
    return {
      ...defaultProps,
      ...finalProps
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be inclined to write your `withDefaults()` function at the end this way:

```
const makeWithDefaults = <T,>() =>
    <K extends keyof T>(defaultProps: Pick<T, K>) =>
        (finalProps: Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>) =>
            ({ ...defaultProps, ...finalProps }) as T;

type MyCompProps = {
    a: string,
    b: string
};

const withDefaults = makeWithDefaults<MyCompProps>();
```

Notice that `makeWithDefaults()` doesn't do much at runtime except return a function, but at compile time you can use the generic parameter `T` to specify the actual object type you're trying to build.

The function it returns uses the utility types [`Pick<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), and [`Omit<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys).

Once `T` is specified, the `withDefaults()` function will accept a `defaultProps` object with any subset of the properties from `T`, and will infer `K` to be the keys of this `defaultProps` object.  The returned function accepts a `finalProps` of type `Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>`.  The `Omit<T, K>` part says that `finalProps` *must* have all the properties from `T` which are missing from `defaultProps`, and the `Partial<Pick<T, K>>` part says that `finalProps` *may* have any of the properties from `T` which were included in `defaultProps`.  And the return type of this function is [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to be the original `T` (this should be true, but the compiler can't verify it).

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const hasDefaultA = withDefaults({ a: "hello" });

const foo = hasDefaultA({ b: "works" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo)); // {"a":"hello","b":"works"}
const bar = hasDefaultA({}); // error! property b missing
const baz = hasDefaultA({ a: "goodbye", b: "works" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(baz)); // { "a": "goodbye", "b": "works" }
```

Looks good.  I don't have specific reactjs experience so I'll defer to others about how to make your `withDefaultProps()` version work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMDqBLKALAIigMwQFcAbKCGAXhgB4AVAGgD4AKASmuYCgY+6A0jBQAPKCjAATSqgCeIAjHptJhEuQAKAJxAAHCAC4YGjMCQNGMAc05Ue-BzFYEMYBKW17DxhFqgZ3WhMzCytmZhgAMhgAeTgsUOtbe0dU1gBvGAA6HNUiMihPfUscrJc3Dx19GABfTgRKegBuGG5uKFldFBgAWVkAYRA4XSLKGnTefgQjaC1XAHNGSb4AIxmoObB57hqmttBIWAB3LDw1ArH4ZHRT-HzyCFo+weHRtnY97gPoGGwGu-UUAAgtQYCccACLhkYNMYAAibAoUikEBw2offbgH4EEAgUF-CCQ8hA6FreFHEBaJAQNF1PbfECkFBZFHzVgAKQAyjEAHJZWYLDAEWTOXHsD4wAD0kpg6ThCDhBgRSJRcMYcJWirhFKpNJqXyxsBWvnx-3OxIydKlMpQWh0WgAhDBdFVbR0YCt4BgIBAFgbDh6EAAvU2E83A6GwuHzXGSFayFBqj1GbWU6m0jEMpkskBsrm8-kbQXC1jGoPilrS2XwhUpmMgOMJpMaxXktM02rcIA)

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my solution as well

You got it right with `Omit`, but to actually use it you will need to infer passed default props type

```
function withDefaultProps<C extends React.ElementType>(Component: C) {
  const ResultComponent = Component as React.FunctionComponent;

  // we return generic function, that accepts Partial component props as argument
  return <D extends Partial<React.ComponentProps<C>>>(defaultProps: D) => (
    // now we have access to D keys and can exclude them from final props with Omit
    finalProps: Omit<React.ComponentProps<C>, keyof D> & {
      // but it needs a little workaround, because it will not have children prop otherwise
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }
  ) => (
    <ResultComponent {...defaultProps} {...finalProps}>
      {finalProps.children}
    </ResultComponent>
  );
}
```

Usage example:
[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-dust-11u7m?file=/src/App.tsx)